# NSUserDefaults plist file is getting removed and not creating again while running the app from Xamarin.UITest

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

We are using NSUserDefaults to store some environment related details (i.e. URL of web service). We are saving the URL in NSUserDefaults once the app is launched. If we launch the application directly from the springboard we are able store and retrieve the values from NSUserDefaults and it is working as expected. But when we run the application through Xamarin.UITest project the plist file for the NSUserDefaults is getting removed and not at all creating again even after calling the NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize() method.

**More Details:**

- App Development: Xamarin.iOS
- Test Project : Xamarin.UITest

**ConfigureApp in UITest Project**

```
app = ConfigureApp
                .iOS
                .PreferIdeSettings()
                .EnableLocalScreenshots()
                .DeviceIdentifier(“guid”)
                .InstalledApp(“bundle_identifier”)
                .StartApp();
```

**Note:** When we use `.StartApp(Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear);` in configuration it is working fine and the plist file is not getting removed. But as per our requirement we need to clear the app data every time during the app launch.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance